# How do I make this question more clear?

Tags: discussion

So I basically wanted to ask to what extent embassies work with each other. I [asked this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/77514/41775)  and it was edited by one of the users but it's still not open. Can anybody suggest me how can I make this question more concrete?

Comment: I think the question is too broad in its current state … and may become primarily opinion-based if restricted further because I doubt there are too many quoteable sources on the topic …

Comment: It looks like your second attempt worked and attracted a few answers, so now there's a happy ending for all concerned.

Comment: Yup. Happy ending indeed :) Still a very confusing question though.

Answer (score 2):

[update] I've tried editting the question as per the below suggestion, because I think it's an interesting question that compliments the asker's other question. Let's see if it gets re-opened.

---

It's *nearly* fine. I was going to try to help make it clearer, then I realised I don't 100% understand what it is you're trying to do or what it is that would "solve" it.

After reading it a couple of times I think your question is basically:

> Under what circumstances can one country's embassy cause another country's embassy to cancel a visa that's already issued?

Does that sound right? If so, edit the title to something like that, which sets the question up as a solvable problem, and you should be fine. You've already got two of the five re-open votes you need.

---

I think this is the issue: Usually questions here, someone has a practical problem (or they're anticipating one they might have) and they're looking for help to solve it. I can see from your question that you're interested in the general topic of under what circumstances embassies share information about people, but it's not clear what information in this topic area would "solve" your problem or satisfy your interest.

That's one of the main differences between this site and discussion forums: we get straight to the answer instead of a roundabout discussion, but, the question has to be phrased like a solvable question or problem, not opening a general discussion of a topic area. It can be a bit tricky to get used to at first.

---

[edit] Oops, I just saw that you'd already figured it out and asked a good new question!

[Is it possible for a Schengen country to advise the US to cancel/revoke a valid visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77523/is-it-possible-for-a-schengen-country-to-advise-the-us-to-cancel-revoke-a-valid)

Ha. Hopefully this will help if you're also interested in combinations other than Schengen and the US and want another question!